# Can I compare the coefficients of the ramp function between two groups in ARIMA model?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, arima, regression-coefficients

I analyzed the impact of a celebrity's disclosure of mental health condition in the monthly incidence of the diagnosis of the celebrity using an interrupted time series analysis (ITA) with the ARIMA model. In the model, a ramp function represented the disclosure event, and `auto.arima` in R gave an output about the best model with coefficients and standard errors for the level and the slope of the ramp function. I did a subgroup analysis by dividing the total population into males and females and reran the analysis in each group. I want to see if the impact of the disclosure is different between males and females. What statistical analysis can be done?

Below are the summaries of the ITA:
1st group

```r
Regression with ARIMA(0,1,1)(1,0,0)[12] errors 

Coefficients:
          ma1    sar1  stepCha  stepLee  rampCha  rampLee
      -0.3657  0.3172  -6.3662   0.4706   4.2881  -1.1185
s.e.   0.0947  0.1005   6.1895   5.9199   1.2267   1.4131

sigma^2 = 43.99:  log likelihood = -391.63
AIC=797.26   AICc=798.26   BIC=816.71
```

2nd group

```r
Regression with ARIMA(0,1,3)(2,0,0)[12] errors 

Coefficients:
          ma1     ma2      ma3    sar1    sar2   stepCha   stepLee  rampCha  rampLee
      -0.7872  0.6552  -0.2714  0.0540  0.5509  -49.2338  -15.8339  23.6277  -7.0684
s.e.   0.1159  0.1203   0.1393  0.0944  0.1043   14.8209   15.1400   2.9894   3.2334

sigma^2 = 324.8:  log likelihood = -513.18
AIC=1046.36   AICc=1048.4   BIC=1074.16
```